# MS Teams - Allow attendees report using Graph API for the online meetings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there any way to allow the attendees to report using Graph API for the online meetings?

as nothing clear from Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) about the property needs to be sent in the request body.

I was able to enable it manually from the MS Team App in the meeting settings, but not able to do it using the Graph API.

Comment: Do you want to get all attendance reports for an online meeting? If so, you can refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Comment: What do you mean by "report"? Maybe share some screen from MS Team App what exactly was enabled.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thanks for your comment … you know to get the attendance report for a meeting you have first to allow the attendance report on the meeting level from here ( open any meeting from MS Team >> click on meeting options >> it will open the options on web >> go to the last choice which is allow attendees report and enable it ) all the previous steps can be done manually .. I am looking for a way to enable it using the graph API

Comment: @mohammadaburahmeh - Microsoft Graph API currently doesn't provide any way to allow attendees to report using Graph API for online meetings. The API documentation for online meetings does not mention any properties that would enable this functionality. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an admin, you control whether meeting organizers can download meeting attendance reports by setting a Teams meeting policy. By default, the ability to download the report is turned on.

Microsoft Graph API currently doesn't provide any way to allow attendees to report using Graph API for online meetings.